# Is there a way in visual studio 2022 to add a new line before and after namespace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Stuido 2022 to code my C# project.

Is there a way to configure VS using (`.editorconfig` file) where a new line is added before and after the namespace?

So my class will look like this

```cs
using System;

namespace ProjectName.Tests;

public class Test
{
    
}
```

instead of

```cs
using System;
namespace ProjectName.Tests;
public class Test
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a Visual Studio native way of doing this.

There is definitely *not* a way to do this in `.editorconfig` with Visual Studio alone (meaning no plugins). About [halfway down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0160-ide0161) [Namespace declaration preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0160-ide0161), it talks about `csharp_style_namespace_declarations`, and the code formatting sample when that value is `file_scoped` looks like

```cs
// csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
using System;

namespace Convention;
class C
{
}
```

which appears to get you part of the way there (blank line after `using`). When you look at the [supported formatting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options), the list is pretty brief.

If you have ReSharper there is a way. These settings in `.editorconfig` will do what you want:

```ini
resharper_blank_lines_after_file_scoped_namespace_directive = 1
resharper_blank_lines_after_imports = 1
```

If ReSharper is not an option, here are 3 possible paths to take, none all that great. They certainly aren't simple solutions.

- try to find something in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/)
- write a .NET Analyzer that is configured via `.editorconfig` (ref. [this page](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=2d00541d10d5f5a0JmltdHM9MTY3NDAwMDAwMCZpZ3VpZD0xOGNmZjhmYS0zYzBiLTY1ZmEtMDkyNy1lYTZiM2QyZTY0YjgmaW5zaWQ9NTQzOA&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=18cff8fa-3c0b-65fa-0927-ea6b3d2e64b8&psq=.net%20analyzer%20quick%20fix&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubXl0ZWNocmFtYmxpbmdzLmNvbS9wb3N0cy9jb25maWd1cmUtcm9zbHluLWFuYWx5emVycy11c2luZy1lZGl0b3Jjb25maWcv&ntb=1))
- raise an issue on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home), and hope they get to it.

Comment: Regarding the last point, [a github issue #67400 at Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/67400) already exists based on Developer Community feedback.

Answer (score 1):

StyleCop.Analyzers has a bunch of formatting related rules that you can enforce and, in some cases, automatically fix across your codebase.

Unfortunately it looks as though there is not yet support for file-scoped namespace formatting in the way you want. There's a PR to add it here, so if you really wanted to have this you could get that PR across the finish line, or make your own build:

https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3512

This issue might also be worth a look:

https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3578

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guy said,

No, not with editor config (out of the box).

**Resharper** can do this; you can build a custom format for your code and tell it, for example, where you want certain sections like imports below the class for some weird reason ;) ...of course, with that spacing around those sections.

But now you have to get ReSharper licenses for all your devs. The Resharper devs are very cool, and Jetbrains has been building quality software for a few decades. Maybe I'm sentimental.

Well, there is another option if you don't want to pay...
In DevOps roles of the past, I've used Roslyn to build extensions for custom formatting.

**Build a custom Rosyln analyzer.**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022#severity-levels-of-analyzers

You can build a custom code suggestion with this of configurable severity.

It's pretty easy, too, thanks to Rosyln, but you must think a little backward. Let me know if I can help more.